# Laravel[PAYPAL] annoying issue with PayPal SDK config fix

Tags: laravel-4, paypal, composer-php

I'm trying to create a laravel wrapper for paypal sdk, but could not continue due to the annoying fact that as a developer we should edit this

```
vendor/paypal/sdk-core-php/lib/../config/sdk_config.ini
```

Is there anyway in the paypal SDK to easily change the config.ini without compromising the structure.

I'm trying not to touch the /vendor/ folder as much as possible.

Or should i create a filesystem editor in my functions that would create an sdk_config.ini for Paypal SDK?

Any concepts?

Comment: You may be interested in my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) which works great with Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with old version like sdk 1.4.0 you can do it by declaring sdk_config path , see [paypal documentation](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/wiki/Configuring-the-SDK)

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue too, found some error on code after updating the sdk. post an issue on Paypal-sdk

https://github.com/paypal/SDKs/issues/51

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**In Composer:**

Check `composer.json` be sure you have:

```
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "*"
```

If you have a different string change it and run `composer update`.

**In your php code:**
So now you should be able to inject the configuration in the following way:

```
$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']);
$this->_api_context = new ApiContext($cred);
$this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
```

Where `$paypal_conf` is:

```
array:3 [▼
   "client_id" => "..."
   "secret" => "..."

   "settings" => array:5 [▼
       "mode" => "sandbox"
       "http.ConnectionTimeOut" => 30
       "log.LogEnabled" => true
       "log.FileName" => "./storage/logs/paypal.log"
       "log.LogLevel" => "FINE"
       ]
   ]
```